# React в textarea не высвечивается новое значение

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Есть вот такая вот конструкция:

```
<button onClick={start_recogn}>Start</button>
<textarea type="text" defaultValue={''} className="word"/>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "старт" происходит какое-то действие и в textarea должно измениться значение, изменяю вот так:

```
element("word").value = last_text;
```

На чистом html все работает нормально, на React'e не работает визуальное отображение, т.е "внутри" значение изменяется, а "снаружи" остается, как было изначально - пустое. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо создать состояние для `textArea` и его менять. Само значение должно передаваться в элемент через атрибут `value`:

```
const [areaText, setText] = useState(''); // Создаем состояние

const start_recogn = () => { // Придуманная функция смены значения
    setText(Math.random().toString())
}

<button onClick={start_recogn}>Start</button>
<textarea defaultValue={''} value={areaText} className="word"/>
```